# Angular 2: ngFor in descention order

Tags: angular

I have a component with an array of items.

Every time the user clicks a button, a new item added to this array.

This array is shown in a ngFor loop this way:

```
    <li *ngFor="let log of Logs" class="list-group-item" [innerHTML]="log"</li>
```

Now, new logs are shown at the bottom of the list. What I'm trying is making the new logs shown at the top of the list.

How it can be done with angular 2?

Comment: You can't change the order of the ngFor. Why don't you use Array.unshift(newLog) to add the new log to the array?

Comment: Thanks @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc, I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom pipe for this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse'
})
export class ReversePipe {
  transform(arr) {
    var copy = arr.slice();
    return copy.reverse();
  }
}
```

(note that I create a copy of the array not to update the source array)

and use it this way:

```
<li *ngFor="let log of Logs | reverse"
    class="list-group-item" [innerHTML]="log"</li>
```

Don't forget to add this pipe into the `pipes` attribute of the component where you use it.

Comment: Shouldn't pipes be added in `pipes` and not `directives`?

Comment: You have to also import `PipeTransform` and say `ReversePipe implements PipeTransform`